# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.org.app.gcm.GcmReceiver

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate

I have android app that is release in the store. While checking the log i found the below error log.

As per the log it seems like an error occurred in GCMReceiver and the Mainapplication line 190 doesn't link to GCM

it has a code getResources().getString(R.string.density_bucket);

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.org.app.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.org.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2955)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.org.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:638)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2935)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
    Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
           at com.org.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:190)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:635)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2935)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```